# Angular rxjs filter observable

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to filter an observable of products with an array of filters but i really don't know how..

Let me explain, I would like to set the result of my filtering to filteredProducts.
For filtering i have to check, for each filter, if the product's filter array contains the name of the filter and if the products values array's contains filter id.

For the moment, the filter works but only with the last selected filter and i'd like to filter products list with all filters in my selectedFilters array. I can have one or multiple filters.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhkjre?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
export class ProductsFilterComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    @Select(FiltersState.getAllFilters) filters$: Observable<any>;
    @Input() products$: Observable<Product[]>;
    filteredProducts$: Observable<Product[]>;
    public selectedFilters = [];

    constructor(
        private store: Store) { super(); }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.dispatch(new GetAllFilters());
    }

    private filterProducts() {
        this.filteredProducts$ = this.products$.pipe(
            map(
                productsArr => productsArr.filter(
                    p =>
                        p.filters.some(f => this.selectedFilters.some(([selectedF]) => selectedF === f.name.toLowerCase()) // Filter name
                            && f.values.some(value => this.selectedFilters.some(([, filterId]) => filterId === value)) // Filter id
                        )
                )
            )
        );
        this.filteredProducts$.subscribe(res => console.log('filtered:', res));
    }
}
```

Here's the structure of a product object
[image: Here's the structure of a product object]

Here's the structure of selectedFilters
[image]

A big thank you in advance :-).

Comment: can you create a minimal reproducible snippet ? i.e. StackBlitz. So that people can understand your issue a bit better

Comment: if you're using ngrx, it sounds like there should be some bit of state like `filteredProducts` that uses both the products and filters from the store.

Comment: @SupunDeSilva Thanks for interesting to my problem. Sure, there's my code :-)

Comment: Well, if possible add declarations of  `GetAllFilters` and `FiltersState`. So if there is something wrong it is easier to spot. Also you have a `BaseComponent` not sure if it is relevant for the issue. In a nut-sell make it easier for the other users to find the issue without having to make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lzw6aa) with an example that works.

To sum it up:

1. We listen to changes in both products and filters, and combine them into a single observable using `combineLatest`:

```js
    const productsAndFilters: Observable<[Product[], ProductFilter[]]> = combineLatest([
      this.products$,
      this.filters$.pipe(startWith(initialFilters)),
    ]);
```

2. Then we pipe the combined observable into a function that actually does the filtering job

```js
    this.filteredProducts$ = productsAndFilters.pipe(
      map(([products, filters]) => {
        return AppComponent.filterProducts(products, filters);
      }),
    )
```

3. Every time `products$` emits a new value, we will update `filteredProducts$`. Every time `filters$` emits a new value, we update them too.
4. Note that `combineLatest` will NOT emit until EACH observable has emitted at least once. For this reason, if your "selectedFilters" do not emit anything in the beginning, you can use `startWith` operator to create an observable with a starting value. This makes sure that `combineLatest` will emit a value as soon as `products$` emits a value.

---

I've also moved the filtering code into a static function:

```js
  private static filterProducts(products: Product[], filters: ProductFilter[]) {
    // we can combine filters into a single function
    // so that the code a tiny bit more readable
    const matchesAllFilters = (product: Product) => filters.every(
        ([filterName, filterValue]) => product.filters
          .some(f => f.name === filterName &&
                     f.values.some(value => value === filterValue))
    );

    return products.filter(matchesAllFilters);
  }
```

In my example I assume that you want ALL filters to be satisfied. If you instead want "AT LEAST ONE" filter to be satisfied, you can change `filters.every` to `filters.some`.

Comment: A real thanks for your help and explanations!
I think i understood what you wanna however I failed to make the logic work. I created a stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fzclx3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: After updating filters list, i log the filtered products and i always get the same results with all products